# CTE Recursively join table

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a table of ids that gets updated with a status code and timestamp every time there is an update for that id, e.g:

```
ID       STATUS     TIMESTAMP
------------------------------------
12345    10         2020-08-01 11:00:01
12345    20         2020-08-01 11:01:24
12345    30         2020-08-01 11:07:42
```

I would like to have all the status changes and times in one row, so I end up with:

```
ID       STATUS     TIMESTAMP           STATUS     TIMESTAMP           STATUS     TIMESTAMP
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12345    10         2020-08-01 11:00:01 20         2020-08-01 11:01:24 30         2020-08-01 11:07:42
```

I can sort of do this by doing a join for each status, so my query looks like this:

```
with T1 as
(SELECT distinct
id as 'ID',
Status as 'STATUS',
Timestamp as 'Time10'
from StatusHistory S
where TimeStamp > '2020-01-07 11:00'
and Timestamp < '2020-01-07 11:10'
and Status = '10'),

T2 as
(SELECT distinct
id as 'ID',
Status as 'STATUS',
Timestamp as 'Time20'
from StatusHistory S
where TimeStamp > '2020-01-07 11:00'
and Timestamp < '2020-01-07 11:10'
and Status = '20')

Select * from T1
join T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
```

This works, but I then have to do this for every status, and there are about 12 different status codes. I have read several examples for doing a cursive join, and understand the concept but am having a lot of trouble actually applying it to my query. Essentially I want to be able to say for the recursive bit is `Status = Previous Status + 10`, **but how to implement this is proving troublesome.**

I don't understand how to grab the most recent status and add 10 to it.

Comment: A SQL query has a fixed number of columns.  Do you know what those columns are for your result set?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I am quite understanding the question. The columns I want in my results are ID, Status and Timestamp and are columns within the statushistory table.

Comment: *"The columns I want in my results are ID, Status and Timestamp"* But you have 3 `status` columns in your expected result set, not 1. Having 2  (or more) columns with the same name in a dataset is generally a bad idea anyway. Many applications do not handle it (well). If the expected output you have *is* correct, why do you want such a denormalised format? If someone has 10 status' on the same day, are you therefore expecting 21 columns? What is the upper limit to the number of status? Considering that the sample we have is 3 in 7 minutes, would that mean you *might* need 400+ columns?

Comment: Ah ok I getcha, timestamp is just one column, so ID hits status 10 at say 11am, then the table gets a new row saying status 20 at 1:02am, and then status 30 at 11:04am etc until it hits the 'finished' status. The reason I want it displayed horizontally is for doing some time difference analysis from one status to the next, i.e how long does it take to get from status 10 to 30, or 10 to 50 etc.

Comment: Analysis of time taken would be better down in rows, not columns. You can easily reference the value of the next/prior time with `LEAD`/`LAG`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then status end) as status_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then timestamp end) as timestamp_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then status end) as status_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then timestamp end) as timestamp_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then status end) as status_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then timestamp end) as timestamp_3
from (select sh.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by timestamp) as seqnum
      from StatusHistory sh
      where TimeStamp > '2020-01-07 11:00' and
            Timestamp < '2020-01-07 11:10'
     ) sh
group by id
```

Comment: That actually worked really well, and was surprisingly quick to return results, but better yet I actually understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff's solution worked perfectly for me, but I have since learned about the PIVOT function, and after some trial and error, found the following gave me the table of results I was after:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
       id,
       status, 
       timestamp 
    FROM StatusHistory
       where TimeStamp > '2020-01-07 11:00'
       and Timestamp < '2020-01-07 11:10'
) dat
PIVOT
(
       MAX(Timestamp) FOR Status IN ([10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60], [70], [80], [90], [100], [170]) 
) pvt
order by 10
```

This gave me results like:

```
ID      10                    20                    30
12345   2020-01-08 11:00:01   2020-01-08 11:01:24   2020-01-08 11:07:42
```